# object.create syntax usage in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var Parent = {};
var child = Object.create(parent);
```

is the above block of code as same as below?

```
var Parent = {};
var child = new Parent();
```

if not what the Object.create thingy do?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Well, does the second one result in a `child` that you can use?

Comment: `var child = Object.create(Parent);` is the same as `var child = function(parent) { function O {} O.prototype = parent; return new O(); }(Parent);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is the above block of code as same as below?

No. Your second example causes a runtime error, because you're trying to call something as a function that isn't a function.

> if not what the Object.create thingy do?

`Object.create` creates a new object setting the object you give it as the new object's prototype. Example:

```
var a = {foo: "bar"};
var b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b.foo);      // "bar", because `b` gets `foo` via its prototype
console.log("foo" in b); // true, because `b` gets `foo` via its prototype
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("foo")); // false, the property is on its prototype
```

`Object.create` also has a second argument which allows you to define properties on the object you're creating, [details on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and (of course) in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5).

---

If you want to use `new Xyz` repeatedly to create objects that all share a common prototype and initialization (commonly called "classes" of objects, but that term is very loose in JavaScript), you do that by writing a *function* (called a "constructor function" when you use it with `new`) and assigning the things that the objects should share to `YourFunction.prototype`, which is what the `new` operator will assign to the objects as their prototype (like `Object.create` assigns the prototype from the argument you give it). E.g.:

```
function Thingy() {
}
Thingy.prototype.foo = "bar";

var a = new Thingy(); // 1. Creates new object
                      // 2. Assigns `Thingy.prototype` as the prototype
                      // 3. Calls Thingy with `this` referencing the new object
console.log(a.foo);   // "bar" because it gets it from its prototype
```

There are use cases for constructor functions, and there are use cases for using `Object.create`. The great thing about JavaScript is you have both.